# How to pass a 'child' struct into a function accepting 'parent' struct?

Tags: inheritance, go, struct

I'm trying to use inheritance in Go, and although inheritance isn't 'technically' supported (as far as I know), you can get similar functionality by using anonymous fields.

Here's how I'm defining 'inheritance' for across two structs:

```
//Parent struct:

type FSEntity struct {
    guid GUIDNumber
}

//Child struct:

type DataBlock struct {
    FSEntity
    data []byte
}
```

I now have a function defined as following, which is supposed to accept an instance of the parent struct `FSEntity`:

```
Put(entity FSEntity) {....}
```

But when I try passing an instance of `DataBlock` (which through inheritance is also `FSEntity`) into the `Put` function above like so:

```
guidNumber := GUIDNumber(1234)
value := []byte("sample string")
dataBLock := DataBlock{FSEntity{guidNumber}, value}

Put(dataBLock)
```

On the last line above, I get this error:

```
cannot use dataBLock (type DataBlock) as type FSEntity in argument to Put
```

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the terminology you're using is causing you problems. In the put, you simply need to reference the inner struct like so; `Put(dataBLock.FSEntity)`

But to clarify, there is no parent/child relationship here. You're using a language feature called embedding and works like composition (ie one type is composed of others) only the things you embed have their fields/methods hoisted to the embedding scope. For that reason you can't pass in the type you're calling the 'child' because there is no polymorphic behavior here like when you inherit from a type, instead you're type is composed of that but you can access it's fields without the extra level of indirection. Since your method accepts the embedded type as an argument, you have to explicitly reference it to pass only that. The outer struct is in no way that type.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So there's no way I can use proper inheritance in Go at all ? Because the functionality I wanted was that inside `Put()`, I am able to access BOTH class's variables, and that won't be possible if I simply do `Put(dataBLock.FSEntity)`

Comment: @Ahmad if you want to be able to access variables on both your structs, you'll have to update `Put`'s definition so it's argument is of type `DataBlock`. There is no inheritance in Go. You have to think about the problem a bit differently. You're trying to leverage polymorphism when it doesn't exist as a concept in the language. If you want that type of dynamic behavior (like a collection that contains many types which are supposed to have some common behavior/fields/ect) then you abstract that behind an interface.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly inheritance and the idea is to define Put as method

```
func (entity FSEntity) Put() {....}
```

then after embedding

```
type DataBlock struct {
    FSEntity
    data []byte
}
```

DataBlock can use this method

```
dataBLock.Put()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve it is to satisfy the parameter's type: pass a `FSEntity`. If you need to only get `FSEntity` from a struct which is embedding it, then you can simply do `dataBlock.FSEntity`.

```
//Parent struct:

type FSEntity struct {
    guid string
}

//Child struct:

type DataBlock struct {
    FSEntity
    data []byte
}

func main() {
    myVar := DataBlock{}
    myVar.guid = "test"
    myVar.data = []byte("moar test")
    a(myVar.FSEntity)
}

func a(x FSEntity) {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
}
```

([Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UFhmuflmv0))

Comment: But the functionality I want is that within Put, I should also be able to access the 'child' structs variables. They way your code is structured, I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Guider interface {
    Guid() string
}
type FSEntity struct {
    guid string
}
func (e FSEntity) Guid() string {
    return e.guid
}

//Child struct:

type DataBlock struct {
    FSEntity
    data []byte
}

func main() {
    myVar := DataBlock{}
    myVar.guid = "test"
    myVar.data = []byte("moar test")
    Put(myVar)
}

func Put(x Guider) {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
}
```

An interface will help you to accept the parent struct